# Deleting emails on iPhone creates new folder "Deleted Messages" in Mac Mail

Tags: iphone, mail.app, icloud

When I delete an email in Mail on my iPhone, it creates a new folder in Mail on my Mac called "Deleted Messages". Why is it doing this and not putting them in the Trash? I am using iCloud mail on both devices.

Comment: Why did you not accept this answer? Based on your comment, it seems to have resolved your issue.

Comment: Sorry, it did not resolve my issue although I'm sure it may solve the issue for someone with a similar problem. My comment does not suggest that it was solved.

Comment: OK. I must be misconstruing it somehow.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I am using Google Apps. I do not see the option for Trash, only Deleted Messages. So, when I "delete" my emails they go to a "Deleted Messages" folder instead of the "Trash" folder. Something of interest, using GMail I see the Trash folder, but with Google Apps for Business I only see the Deleted items folder.

Answer (score 4):

You can tell iOS which folder it should use for your deleted messages. Open up the Settings app and follow this path:

```
Mail, Contacts, Calendars < YOURACCOUNT (iCloud) < Account < Advanced (Mail) < Advanced
```

There you'll see Mailbox Behaviors options to tell iOS which folders to use for Drafts, Sent, and Deleted messages.

In your case, tap Deleted Mailbox and navigation your mail account's hierarchy to find your existing Trash folder. Select that and everything should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I found the settings above but next to the trash icon it says "Deleted Messages", I assume iCloud then sees this a new folder and adds it to mac mail. The only option to select for trash in settings stores the trash on the iPhone.

Comment: Do you have a box of other folders in that inbox? If so, is there a Trash folder buried further down in the hierarchy? Out of curiosity have you have this iCloud account for awhile? I seem to remember having a bunch of IMAP Trash folder sync issues back in the .Mac/MobileMe days.

Answer (score 0):

For syncing with iCloud you need to choose folder "Deleted Messages" on your iPhone to be default for the Deleted Mailbox. Otherwise it will create a new Folder on the server called TRASH and the emails you delete on your iPhone will in mail on your computer only be seen in this folder and not in the general Trash.